# How to generate ActiveRecord query for

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question about ActiveRecord queries:
What's the best way to write AR for a query like so:

```
SELECT .* FROM `professionals` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `networks` 
  ON `networks`.`userable_id` = `professionals`.`id` 
  AND `networks`.`userable_type` = 'Professional'
WHERE (`networks`.`insurer_id` IS NULL OR (`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1))
```

The most trouble I'm having is with this part within the query:

```
WHERE (`networks`.`insurer_id` IS NULL OR (`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1))
```

I am able to generate that above query with this:

```
professionals.left_joins(:networks)
  .where(networks: { insurer_id: nil })
  .or(
  professionals.left_joins(:networks)
    .where.not(networks: { insurer_id: @insurer&.id }))
```

Which is quite insanely smelly because it looks as if I'm repeating part of the query within the first query. Is there a way for me to write it better?

I've been having quite a lot of trouble when using `WHERE NOT` and chaining `OR` queries in Rails. So when they eventually all exist at the same time, I'm really out of luck.

EDIT>>>>>>>
Not having the NULL condition seems to ignore the other items of the LEFT JOIN...

```
[4] pry(main)> Professional.left_joins(:networks).where.not(networks: {insurer_id: 1}).count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `professionals` LEFT OUTER JOIN `networks` ON `networks`.`userable_id` = `professionals`.`id` AND `networks`.`userable_type` = 'Professional' WHERE (`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1)
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I had wrong:

1. In a LEFT JOIN you can't put a WHERE condition without essentially turning your result set into an INNER JOIN ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501024/left-outer-join-with-a-where-clause))
2. LEFT JOINing on polymorphic associations, with your custom AND condition is a bad idea because since its a LEFT JOIN, it won't filter out rows from your additional AND condition. It will simply include them there (because of the polymorphic association ANDs) but will NULL fields.

Ultimately I replaced my previous query with:

```
professionals.where.not(id: 
    Network.select(:userable_id)
        .where(insurer_id: @insurer.id, userable_type: 'Professional'))
```

Which works just the same. It boils down to a nested SELECT query in SQL.

Comment: Please note that if `Network.select(:userable_id).where(insurer_id: @insurer.id, userable_type: 'Professional')` ever happens to contain a `NULL` value you will not get any response because `NOT IN (NULL)` will always evaluate false and no record set will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is refactor your SQL before switching it to AR:

```
SELECT .* FROM `professionals` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `networks` 
  ON `networks`.`userable_id` = `professionals`.`id` 
  AND `networks`.`userable_type` = 'Professional'
WHERE (`networks`.`insurer_id` IS NULL OR (`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1))
```

If an insurer ID is NOT 1, then is NULL a valid value? I would say so. you should be able to replace

```
(`networks`.`insurer_id` IS NULL OR (`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1))
```

with

```
`networks`.`insurer_id` != 1
```

Which leaves us with

```
SELECT .* FROM `professionals` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `networks` 
  ON `networks`.`userable_id` = `professionals`.`id` 
  AND `networks`.`userable_type` = 'Professional'
WHERE `networks`.`insurer_id` != 1
```

which should be a TON easier to query using AR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - similar to what I mentioned to @engineersmnky on the other answer above, it seems that  something is confusing AR on the outer join...

Answer (score 1):

So I am going to make some assumptions here and hopefully your set up is like so

```
class Professional 
  has_many :networks, as: :userable
end 

class Network
   belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then the following should work appropriately (using Arel)

```
net = Network.arel_table

Professional.left_joins(:networks)
  .where(net[:insured_id].not_eq(@insured.id)
    .or(net[:insured_id].eq(nil)))
```

This will generate the SQL you posted assuming `@insured.id` returns 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however, AR returns an empty array when I don't have the NULL condition explicitly stated. Its almost as if its doing an inner join somhow :/

Comment: @mhz Okay well I did provide you with a query that replicates your original. Have you tried that one?

Comment: Yes I have, and it returns an empty list of me

Comment: @mhz please add `to_sql` to the end of it and post the output of the running query. The query should match your original so if it does not I need to see what the output looks like in order to be able to help

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the output you asked for.

Comment: @mhz that output does not make sense and is not even valid SQL where does `user_insurers` come from? Please post the actual output of my first suggestion by just adding `to_sql` to the end of it. What you have posted cannot be correct

Comment: Sorry, I ended up re-naming my model mid-way to `user_insurers` instead of `networks`. I put it back to `networks` in my edit.

Also, I was googling around, and it might be a matter of putting an AND condition within the ON of the LEFT JOIN instead of using WHERE... Still working on it

Comment: @mhz I have updated my first query and can confirm that it will output the requested SQL. If you still get no results then your SQL is incorrect for your purpose or your data does not reflect what you think it should